# return null when get value from XML in SQL

Tags: sql, xml, variables

## return null , when use variable for get value in XML

```
   DECLARE @source nvarchar(2000);
    set @source = 'MinExpected'
    select MinimumExpectedProperties.value('(DepnaRoot[.= 
    sql:variable("@source")]/Type)[1]','int') from tbl_AppWFTiming
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use , bellow code

```
DECLARE @source nvarchar(2000);
set @source = 'MinExpected'
select MinimumExpectedProperties.value('(//*[local-name()= 
sql:variable("@source")]/Type)[1]','int') from tbl_AppWFTiming
```

Comment: tank you for help